# What do LISTEN and ports mean in netstat?

Tags: networking, security

I have been monitoring my system lately and I have found some strange things are running on my system. Can anyone please explain what they are and why same program use several processes? Output of `netstat` and `ps -aux`:

```
netstat -antplF
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name<br>
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -      <br>         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -     <br>          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -   <br>             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -    <br>           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -    <br>           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -   <br>            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -     <br>          
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -     <br>          
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:44952     144.76.244.204:443      ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:49334     66.196.66.212:443       ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox    <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:40249     69.171.235.19:443       ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox  <br>  
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:51498     173.194.39.246:443      ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox    <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:39152     198.252.206.24:80       ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:49050     2.20.142.212:80         ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:56883     74.125.136.84:443       ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:39153     198.252.206.24:80       ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:50371     142.0.72.109:3389       ESTABLISHED 5777/xfreerdp   <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:56903     66.196.120.54:5050      ESTABLISHED 5809/pidgin     <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:51073     66.196.120.77:5050      ESTABLISHED 5809/pidgin     <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:54875     193.149.89.57:443       ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox    <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:40648     152.163.0.143:80        ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox    <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:53681     173.194.116.106:443     ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.100:51012     91.189.89.144:80        CLOSE_WAIT  3829/ubuntu-geoip-p<br>
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.100:44527     91.189.89.31:80         CLOSE_WAIT  3871/gvfsd-http <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:47284     74.125.136.94:443       ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:36697     173.194.66.95:80        ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:37008     173.194.44.52:443       ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:40558     66.196.121.49:5050      ESTABLISHED 5809/pidgin     <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:56115     172.227.184.65:443      ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:35533     66.196.120.117:5050     ESTABLISHED 5809/pidgin     <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:57169     64.4.44.81:443          ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox    <br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:58695     198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.100:43395     213.157.220.180:443     ESTABLISHED 2705/chromium-brows<br>
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -    <br>           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -    <br>           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -    <br>           
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      - <br>              
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      - <br>              
tcp6       1      0 ::1:33153               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  -<br>
```

What are the LISTEN ports and IPs at the beginning and the end? Why are they like `0.0.0.0:*` for any ip and any port? What does it mean? What are they used for, exactly, please?

Comment: ... And your problem is?

Comment: what is the LISTEN ports and ip at the beginning and the end and why its like 0.0.0.0:* for any ip and any port this means ? for what used exactly please ?

Comment: I have those too, they are for various programs to work.

Answer (score 8):

1. 631 is used by CUPS (the print service daemon).
2. 445 is used by Samba (used to share files with Windows PCs over the network).
3. 139 is used by [`nmbd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/nmbd.8.html), part of the Samba setup.
4. 25 and 527 are SMTP ports. You have a mail server running on your system.
5. 53 is used by the DNS server.
6. 111 is used for [Remote Procedure Calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Procedure_Call). Some services depend on this.
7. 80, of course, is the HTTP port.

See the list of [standard ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports).

The `Local Address` [tells you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882/how-do-i-interpret-netstat-a-output) what interface it is listening on (`127.0.0.1` is `localhost`, and `0.0.0.0` means all interfaces). If a remote system has connected to a port, `Foreign Address` [will show](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301778/foreign-address-associated-with-netstat) the address of that system, and `0.0.0.0` otherwise.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what the **LISTEN** state means, which was the main question!

Comment: @Alvar `LISTEN` means that a service is listening for requests on that port - which is obvious. Your question is unclear as it is. Only you know what the main question is.

Comment: read the comments? *what is the LISTEN ports and ip at the beginning and the end and why its like 0.0.0.0:* for any ip and any port this means ? for what used exactly please ? –  alex trace*

Comment: @Alvar those comments should be edited into the question, and it's not my fault if they were in the comments. I have explained the various LISTEN ports listed, and the why the IP is 0.0.0.0 or something else. In my view, I have covered everything that was asked, including the comments.

Answer (score 7):

**Listen:**

Those lines show services you have running, waiting to be contacted

**Established**

Network connections that are active

**Close_wait**

Network connections that are about to being closed

**Local address**

- Services: here you see the local IP-address, where that service is listening **and** (after a `:`) the port it is listening on, with

  - 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1 (for IPv6): localhost, the loop back interface - those services can only be contacted from your local machine
  - 0.0.0.0:xxx, :::xxx  : any local address:port-number
- active connections: the IP-address and the port used by that special connection

**Foreign address**

- Services: IP-adresses from where this service can be contacted (0.0.0.0:* = from everywhere, using any remote port)
- active connections: the IP-address and port of the "partner" in the communication

**examples**

- `tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`: you have a service running, that listens for connections on port 25 (apparently a mail server) only from the local host
- `tcp 0 0 192.168.0.100:51498 173.194.39.246:443 ESTABLISHED 6796/firefox`: Firefox has established a connection to the https port on 173.194.39.246

**ports??**

Those are just numbers, used to distinguish between connection end point on one machine, no two programs on one machine may use the same port simultaneously.